# adding the sum of two select count queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I have two tables and I'm trying to see how many rows both tables contain. They have no common field on which they can join. Below is my query so far, which obviously doesn't work. How should it be?

```
;with tblOne as
(
    select count(*) numRows from tblOne where DateEx = '2015-10-27'
),
tblTwo as
(
    select count(*) numRows from tblTwo where Status = 0
)
select tblOne.numRows + tblTwo.numRows
```

Comment: `SELECT t1.numRows + t2.numRows FROM tblOne t1 CROSS JOIN tblTwo t2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need CTEs; you can just change them to subqueries:

```
select 
    (select count(*) numRows from tblOne where DateEx = '2015-10-27') +   
    (select count(*) numRows from tblTwo where Status = 0)
```

If you REALLY want to use CTEs then just do an implicit CROSS JOIN:

```
with tblOne as
(
    select count(*) numRows from tblOne where DateEx = '2015-10-27'
),
tblTwo as
(
    select count(*) numRows from tblTwo where Status = 0
)
select tblOne.numRows + tblTwo.numRows
FROM tblOne, tblTwo
```

Comment: May I ask *why* an implicit CROSS JOIN instead of an explicit one?

Comment: @Lamak No strong reason - just a shorter syntax, and no concern about cartesian product issues since each subquery is only one record.  I prefer the subqueries to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `cross join`:

```
with tblOne as (
      select count(*) as numRows from tblOne where DateEx = '2015-10-27'
     ),
     tblTwo as (
      select count(*) as numRows from tblTwo where Status = 0
     )
select tblOne.numRows + tblTwo.numRows
from tblOne cross join tblTwo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use union and query from that

```
select sum(numRows) as numRows from (
    select count(*) numRows from tblOne where DateEx = '2015-10-27'
    union all
    select count(*) numRows from tblTwo where Status = 0
)
```

edit: Added union all, so if it happens that both queries have same amount of rows the both results are included.